# Overloading in inheritance

Tags: java

So I came across this concept of overloading resolution while studying Dynamic programming but I am having trouble understanding this. The statement goes like this-
"If the compiler cannot  find any method with matching parameter type or if multiple methods all match after applying conversions(casts) the compiler reports an error"

I tried verifying the statement with help of an example and it goes like following-

```
public class OverloadingResolution{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClassB b= new ClassB();
        b.check(3);
        ClassB c=new ClassC();
        c.check(3)
    }
}

class ClassA{
    public void check(float a){
        System.out.println("Inside ClassA----> value of a is"+a);
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA{
    public void check(float a){
        System.out.println("Inside ClassB----> value of a is"+a);
    }
}

class ClassC extends ClassB{
    public void check(short a){
        System.out.println("Inside ClassC----> value of a is"+a);
    }
}
```

The outcome was: 
 
Inside ClassB value--->value of a is 3.0 
Inside ClassB value--->value of a is 3.0

My doubt is I expected a compile time error as `ClassB b= new ClassB();`, since b has multiple methods with matching parameters.

Comment: "_b has multiple methods with matching paramters_" It does not. Since the method signature is the same as the parent, you have orverridden the method.

Comment: Can a short be converted to a float? Yes, therefore the signature of the two methods are the same.

Comment: @takendarkk what if classA was to have a method with explicit parameter of type double  public void check(double a)

Comment: Well I understand method overriding is happening here so I stand corrected but now my question is if ClassA has a method check with signature like public void check(double a) then for b.check(3) casting will happen now will it throw error as for b there are 2 methods check(float a) and check(double a) and call being made is b.check(int a)

Answer (score 0):

**The output is correct as there is no method overriding being performed in class C, class C does not overrides the check() method of class B, check method in class C is treated as a separate method of class C.**

> Note:- you are performing Method Overriding in the code and not Method Overloading, Method Overloading can be done in single class. Method overloading means same method name same class but different parameters in method . In Method Overriding there will be more than one class.
>
> RULES FOR METHOD OVERRIDING :
>
> 1.The method must have the same name as in the parent class
>
> 2.The method must have the same parameter as in the parent class.
>
> 3.There must be an IS-A relationship (inheritance).

According to you : "If the compiler cannot find any method with matching parameter type" -> compiler finds the method check() in class B so it is not giving compile time error.

Please refer to [Overloading](https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java) and [Overriding](https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overriding-in-java)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but method overloading requires same signature it is not necessary for methods to be in same class. They can exist in different  class but the 2 class are supposed to be related (inheritance)

Comment: @Sarthak you are telling about Method Overriding, "method overriding requires same signature it is not necessary for methods to be in same class(they cant be in same calss). They can exist in different class but the 2 class are supposed to be related (inheritance)"
Method Overloading is performed in same class but Method Overriding is performed in different classes which have an IS-A relationship(inheritance).